# MeteorJS: Can't manage to deploy meteor app on Android emulator/device

Tags: cordova, meteor

I'm running Linux Mint 17 (based on Ubuntu 14.04)
I tried to run my meteor app both on emulator and device.

Please note I had to use **sudo** to prevent the following error:

> Error while running for mobile platforms: EACCES, unlink
>   '/home/manuel/__DEV/*PROJECTS*/__test/simple-todos/.meteor/local/cordova-build/resources/android_hdpi.icon.png'

On **emulator**:

```
sudo meteor run android
Starting android emulator                     
[[[[[ ~/__DEV/_PROJECTS_/__test/simple-todos ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started MongoDB.                           
=> Started app on Android Emulator.           
=> Started your app.                          

=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
```

The emulator is shown and loaded. However **no app is loaded and I can't find it in application drawer either**.
Also if I try to open the browser (in the emulator) and go to **http://localhost:3000/**, it tells me it doesn't exist (while on PC it works at the same time). The PC and the Android device are on the same wifi network.

On **device**:

```
sudo meteor run android-device
WARNING: You are testing your app on a remote device.For the mobile app to be
         able to connect to the local server, make sure your device is on the
         same network, and that the network configuration allows clients to
         talk to each other (no client isolation).
[[[[[ ~/__DEV/_PROJECTS_/__test/simple-todos ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started MongoDB.                           
=> Started app on Android Device.             
I20150804-19:27:46.494(2)? - waiting for device -
=> Started your app.                          

=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
```

In this case after **-waiting for device-**, it skips straights to app running on http://localhost:3000/. In fact on PC it works.
I tried to install adb and run **adb devices** (even with sudo) and no way  I can manage to list the android devices there, not even by using **adb over wifi** (and connecting via **adb connect** which on Windows always worked seamlessly.

Any clue on how I can troubleshoot this?

Comment: I can't provide an answer, but I'll join you in waiting for one ;-) I'm having the same issue on Mac 10.10.5. I'm running Meteor 1.1.0.3. It says it's running and gives no error, however there is no app visible in my list of apps on either the device or the emulator (run separately of course). Meanwhile, as you said, the app continues to be served on localhost:3000 on my laptop.

Comment: Add `--verbose` to see why the app isn't running on andfoid-device. To use adb you need to use a specific path (the meteor ab rather than the regular one)

Comment: ~/.meteor/android_bundle/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb

Comment: It seems that since meteor 1.2 you can just use adb instead of the path I gave

Comment: yes, looks working much better

Answer (score 0):

I've found several potential issues to solve.

1. Make sure in addition to Meteor and Cordova you have Apache Ant and Gradle installed.
2. If not running SUDO, make sure all files in .meteor are set to your ownership
3. Load the AVD device from the Android SDK (`android avd`), select device,  click start, and make sure you select delete all user data option
4. if meteor run android still fails to load the app, in terminal go to the `.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova` and type `./build` You can watch the build process for errors and make sure the .apk is created
5. Assuming the build works ok, type `./run`and it should now load up fine into the emulator. If not, look back through the run output and see where things are breaking down.
6. It *should* then work when you type `meteor run android`.  If that fails to update the app, perform step 3 again (clear the AVD user data)

None of this had anything to do with Meteor as far as I could tell. I have testing this on a virtualbox and it worked fine despite comments saying it wouldn't work.